# How to prevent a 'pressed Button' from getting unpressed when I pull down the status bar or minimize the app using Java in android studio?

Tags: android, android-button, android-statusbar, onsaveinstancestate

I am working on a project where a button should stay pressed when the user touches or taps on it. I have done it successfully using:

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        button.setPressed(true);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Now, my problem is: when I pull down the status bar or minimize the app using home/back button (from navigation bar), the button becomes unpressed.

I have tried to solve this using:

```
onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

to save the pressed state of the button, but it didn't work.

Now, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save an activity state using save instance state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-to-save-an-activity-state-using-save-instance-state)

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem, because I have tried using onSaveInstanceState, but it didn't work. onSaveInstanceState only works when I rotate the screen, but it doesn't work when I pull down the status bar or minimize the app.

Comment: You probably want `onPause` and `onResume`.

Comment: How do **onPause** and **onResume** work? I have no idea. Would you provide me with specific code? @JakeLee

Comment: Hey you should only need onResume. So store the button state in an instance field boolean. Then override onResume as follows: @Override onResume(){super.onResume(); if(buttonPressed){button.setPressed(true);}}

Comment: **onPause** and **onResume** only works when I minimize the app. But when I pull down the status bar, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found two solutions to this (I personally like the second one).

**Solution 1**

Firstly, I have used `onResume()` and a flag variable to save the button's state when user minimizes the app.

Secondly, I have used `onWindowFocusChanged()` and that same flag variable to save the button's state when user pulls down the status bar.

Demo code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;

    int flag=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                button.setPressed(true);
                flag=1;

                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if(flag==1){
            button.setPressed(true);
        }else{
            button.setPressed(false);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        // handle when the user pull down the notification bar where
        // (hasFocus will ='false') & if the user pushed the
        // notification bar back to the top, then (hasFocus will ='true')

        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

        if (!hasFocus) {
            Log.i("Tag", "Notification bar is pulled down");

        }
        else {
            Log.i("Tag", "Notification bar is pushed up");
            if(flag==1){
                button.setPressed(true);
            }else{
                button.setPressed(false);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Solution 2:**

Firstly, I have created a file in drawable named **button_bg.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_selected="false" android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_disabled">
    </item>


    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_default">
    </item>


    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_default">
    </item>


    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_default">
    </item>

</selector>
```

Create two files in drawable (**button_disabled.xml** & **button_default.xml**) which are used in **button_bg.xml**.

**button_disabled.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#b6b7b5" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="7dp"
        android:left="7dp"
        android:right="7dp"
        android:top="7dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#050303" />

    <corners android:radius="15dp" />

</shape>
```

**button_default.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid
        android:color="#6FA803"/>


    <padding
        android:bottom="7dp"
        android:left="7dp"
        android:right="7dp"
        android:top="7dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#050303" />

    <corners android:radius="15dp" />

</shape>
```

Then, I have added this `button_bg.xml` file as a background of my button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Lastly, I have used `setOnClickListener()` and `View.setSelected()` to select the button view and stay pressed:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        v.setSelected(true);

    }
});
```

The reason I like the second solution is: I don't need to handle the button's state manually. So, when I will be working on with several buttons, the second solution will be more handy.